# "Launch slave agent via Java Web Start" option not availabe whilce creating Node in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

While I am creating slave node "Launch slave agent via Java Web Start" option not available in lunch option while creating node.

To make available this option need to install windows service?

but
"Install as a Windows service" option is not available in "Manage jenkins"

Can you help me to get option "Launch slave agent via Java Web Start"?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You don't need to install windows service - and it should be under node configuration and not in Manage Jenkins. again - when you're adding a new slave you have no option to lunch it using JNLP? Which version of Jenkins Master are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Jenkins dashboard -> `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure Global Security`

Click on `Enable Security`, if not already checked.

Select the `Random` radio button for `TCP port for JNLP agents` option.

Save this config

and create a new node. You should find the option for Jenkins 2.x versions.

Comment: This solved my problem with Jenkins 2.34 and should be accepted.